# compare Filecontent Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file, compare

Apache Commons IO FileUtils.contentEquals() compares 2 files.

Is this also possible using code from eclipse.org ?

Comment: do you mean from inside an eclipse plugin you're writing? what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is equivalent eclipse code, but you could just use the apache code.

The [Orbit project](http://www.eclipse.org/orbit/overview.php) at Eclipse provides bundled versions of third party libraries for use in Eclipse projects.  Apache Commons IO versions [1.3.2](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/S20090426201227/bundles/org.apache.commons.io_1.3.2.v20080604-1500.jar) and [1.4.0](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/S20090426201227/bundles/org.apache.commons.io_1.4.0.v20081110-1000.jar) are both available there.